# No suitable driver found for com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to know why I get this JDBC connection error. I already added the SQL driver in classpath.

When I try use init parameter

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/addServlet",initParams= {@WebInitParam(name="dburl",value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"),
        @WebInitParam(name="dbUser",value="test"),@WebInitParam(name="dbPassword",value="test")})
```

And right this line

```java
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("dbURL"+ config.getInitParameter("dburl"));
        System.out.println("dbUSER"+config.getInitParameter("dbUser"));
        System.out.println(config.getInitParameter("dbPassword"));
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(config.getInitParameter("dburl"),config.getInitParameter("dbUser"),config.getInitParameter("dbPassword"));
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","test","test");
        System.out.println(con);

        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost/mydb:3306","test","test");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "test", "test");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "test", "          test");
        System.out.println(con);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By normal connection with this `//con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","test","test");` I am able to connect to the database, but if I try using initParmas as below it gives me an error.

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection(config.getInitParameter("dburl"),config.getInitParameter("dbUser"),config.getInitParameter("dbPassword"));
```

Error as below

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
  at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
  at com.test.user.servlet.CreateUserServlet.init(CreateUserServlet.java:44)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:649)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:115)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Mar 21, 2024 4:44:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.test.user.servlet.CreateUserServlet] in context with path [/UserApp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.con" is null
```

Comment: You need to carefully read the exception message, and understand what it is telling you. The error includes the JDBC URL that was tried, so it means that `config.getInitParameter("dburl")` returns the string `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, which is not a JDBC URL! This is because you specified `@WebInitParam(name="dburl",value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")`, and not a valid/recognized JDBC URL. Fix your configuration to, for example, `@WebInitParam(name="dburl",value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb")`. Voting to close as caused by a typo.